# How to mock a service method that returns Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

Here is the function that throws error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$userData')`:

`get $userData(): Observable<UserData> { return this.$state.pipe(map(state => state?.userData || undefined)); }`

This method is used in another service's constructor, and I have a problem with mocking the service that has $userData

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a mock service which returns observable.

For example, like that:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ... your current configuration

    // you need to add a mock.
    providers: [
      {
        provide: StateService, // <- replace it with the right service for this.$state
        useValue: of({
          userData: undefined, // put here the value you need in your tests.
        }),
      },
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
});
```